# Java Library which dependencies are provided by implementing app

Tags: java, gradle, dynamic, jar, linker

I am working with Gradle and two separate projects where one project is going to be a library that I want to compile into an implementable jar, which can be used in the other project (app) and also in other projects as well.

In my library I depend on Java Boot and some Google libraries. What do I need to specify in the Gradle file of my library that on compilation the Java Boot and other libraries are not compiled into that jar blowing up its size?

My app implementing my library jar is supposed to provide these libraries. Would I need to specify anything specific in my Gradle file of my app in this scenario?

Comment: can you provide more details about the library project? you say it has some dependencies on Java Boot (do you mean SpringBoot?)  if so, do you want to package this library into a SpringBoot executable/fatjar with part of the dependencies included?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant Spring boot

Comment: The app will have all necessary Spring Boot dependencies included. The library is therefore not supposed to „bring“ any compiled Spring Boot libraries into its compiled code. The library will need to make use of Spring Boot Code at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the library project's dependencies as `compileOnly`:

```
dependencies {
  compileOnly group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0-jre'
}
```

This way your dependency will not be exported and not be packaged into any artifacts.

If you need this dependency in tests you'll need to at it to the `testImplementation` configuration as well.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

From this part of your question :

> [...] the Java Boot and other libraries are not compiled into that jar blowing up its size.

I understand that you have applied the Springboot plugin to your library (which by default produces a fat jar will all dependencies included), while you just want to create a simple/plain java library .

If my assumption is correct, the simplest solution is to use Springboot plugin only for the dependencies management, without actually applying it to your project, as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation).

You should also apply the [Gradle Java library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html), to benefit from the API/Implementation separation feature.

Sample build script for the library project:

```
plugins {
    id "java-library"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.4.RELEASE"  apply false // do not apply it
}
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot deps 
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"

    // libraries you want to "propagate to consumers
    // api group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.0'

    // libraries you don"t want to flow in consumers projects
    // implementation ....

    // Test deps
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}
```